# Excel- Copy and sort a list dynamically:

Tags: excel, sorting

I am trying to condense a list so that there are no duplicates and that it updates automatically as new data is added.
Here is a simpler version of what I am trying to do:
Sheet 2:
Column A:     Column B:
Mint               1
Chocolate          2
Mint               1
Chocolate          1
Vanilla            5

The, on sheet 1 I want a summary so it will say:
Column A:      Column B:
Mint               2
Chocolate          3
Vanilla            5

I am able to do this, however when a totally new flavor is added that I have not seen before and no way to predict (say a new monthly flavor), how can I update it so that it will automatically be added to my summary page. Also in case an old flavor is added, it continues to add it to the appropriate column.

For example, say I add on to my original sheet 2 so it looks like the following-
Column A:     Column B:
Mint               1
Chocolate          2
Mint               1
Chocolate          1
Vanilla            5
Mint               4
Chocolate          2
Special            2
Brownie            8

I know want the Summary sheet to look like the following:
Column A:         Column B:
Mint               6
Chocolate          5
Vanilla            5
Special            2
Brownie            8

Comment: Have a look at the Advanced Filter functionality offered in the Data ribbon. You will also be able to automate that with the help of a macro.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub dynamicSumNSort()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Copy Destination:= Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    While activecell.value <> vbNullString
        activecell.offset(0,1).FormulaR1C1 ="=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C,Sheet2!C[-1],Sheet1!RC[-1])"
        activecell.offset(1,0).select
    Wend
End Sub
```

Try that for size, let me know if you encounter any issues
EDIT: my apologies, I have corrected my error

Comment: have now had a chance to test this code. It seems to work a treat.